# How to retrieve the table names or CONTENT URIs of a provider of a 3rd party application?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am developing an application, which can query content providers of other installed applications. I got the provider name using GET_PROVIDERS, but how do i get the uri with which i can actually query? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i get the uri with which i can actually query?

Contact the developers of the app and ask them.

There is no way to determine, automatically, what valid paths might be for the `Uri`. So, while you know the scheme and a candidate authority from `PackageManager`, everything else from there is non-discoverable. Similarly, you have no idea whether the `ContentProvider` in question is providing streams, database records, or both.